# Position the point in the center on Highcharts even if the Timezone is not UTC

Tags: php, highcharts

I have tried every possible thing but because my timezone is set to `America/New_York` my points are like `5px` right to the actual tick. (I really tried to do everything and was googling for an answer whole the day)

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/json");

include('../includes/config.php');

$tablename = "analytics";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT date, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS date2, COUNT(*) AS count FROM $tablename GROUP BY date(date) DESC LIMIT 7");


$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    $total = $row["count"];
    $rows[$i] = array( gmdate( strtotime($row['date2']) )*1000, $total);

    $i++;
}

echo json_encode($rows);

?>
```

Here is the result i get:
[image: result]

*Don't put attention to the note about Labels not centered, i've found that you can't center the labels if the type of the `xAxis` is `datetime`.

Can someone help please?

Comment: Can you show your plotting code?  HighCharts should center given GM/UTC time: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/Jx5n2/.

Answer (score 0):

> $rows[$i] = array( gmdate( strtotime($row['date2']) )*1000, $total);

You're using gmdate, which returns the time in GMT. If you're storing 00:00 in your database, gmdate will return 05:00.

Just changing it to date should fix this:

> $rows[$i] = array( date( strtotime($row['date2']) )*1000, $total);

Comment: actually i has that before the `gmdate` and i found that there is no difference at all - both are showing the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Highcharts global settings

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: false
    }
 });
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#global.useUTC

Comment: Making suggestions is more suited as a comment, instead of an answer.